# WSL2: I'm trying to run this command "docker-compose up -d --build" and it throws an error "permission denied: unknown"

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown

This is the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN set -e; \
    apt-get update ;\
    apt-get -y install netcat-traditional ;\
    apt-get -y install gettext ;

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN set -e; \
    /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip ;\
    python -m pip install -r /code/requirements.txt ;\
    chmod +x /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh ;

EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is related to the `set -e` command, it is a shell option that causes the shell to exit immediately if any command in the script fails with a non-zero exit status.

You can try it like this,

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install netcat-traditional \
    && apt-get -y install gettext \
    && mkdir /code

COPY . /code/ WORKDIR /code

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
    && python -m pip install -r /code/requirements.txt \
    && chmod +x /code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8000 

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/docker/entrypoints/entrypoint.sh"]
```